# getting value of checkbox, inside a datatable

Tags: primefaces

I have a dataTable and in each cell of the table i have one checkbox. My code is something like this.
My problem is that i am getting only last checkbox value. None of other checkbox is getting binded to backing bean.

Please help to get values if all marked checkboxes.

```
<p:dataTable id="dataT" value="#{bean.dataList} var="data">
   <p:column> 
     <h:outputLabel value="#{data.id}"/>
   </p:column>
   <p:columns id="basic" value="#{bean.list2} var="lst">
     <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="#{lst.header}" />
        </f:facet>      
      <p:selectManyCheckbox value="#{bean.checkBoxList}"> 
       <f:selectItem itemLabel="Xbox One" itemValue="Xbox One" />
     <p:selectManyCheckbox>
</p:dataTable>
```

Comment: You mean you only get the values of the last `p:selectManyCheckbox`? Well, you iterate over the dataList in the data var, but you bind ALL to the same checkBoxList, so the behaviour is exactely as you implemented it. See the PF basic example: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/basic.xhtml or with editing: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/edit.xhtml

Comment: I want all marked checkboxes value. Any suggestions on how to achieve that?

Comment: By doing something like `<p:selectManyCheckbox value="#{data.checkBoxList}">` and giving the data object a field for the checkboxes. It's kind of identical to getting all plain inputs...

Comment: I did that, but that is binding checkboxes of last column..

Comment: Sorry data should be lst

Comment: That is storing checkmarx values of only last row.

Comment: Seriously? Please create an [mcve] then and post all relevant version and implementation info (PF, JSF (MyFaces/Mojarra)

Answer (score 0):

You're using bean.checkBoxList in every row, like kukeltje said you get the expected behaviour.

You could store the lst in your dataObject and add a value attribute:

HTML:

```
 <p:columns id="basic" value="#{data.list2} var="lst">
 <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="#{lst.header}" />
    </f:facet>      
  <p:selectManyCheckbox value="#{lst.checkBoxList}"> 
   <f:selectItem itemLabel="Xbox One" itemValue="Xbox One" />
 <p:selectManyCheckbox></p:columns>
```

Comment: 1. This is storing only checkmarx values of last row

Comment: 2. This is storing only checkmarx values of last column

Comment: I've updated the answer. There are some other more complex ways if you're not able to add the list to your data object. But they're more complex and I'd go this way if possible.